# How to execute a function after opening a Dialog?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, yui, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I need to excute a function after opening a Dialog.
I tried with the following:

```
Liferay.Util.openWindow({
    dialog: {centered: true}, 
    id:'myID', 
    title: 'Title', 
    uri: _url 
});
alert("Loading Complete");
```

I get the `alert()` after the opening of dialog but before the request is complete.
How can I execute a function after loading of the Dialog and after the request is completed?

I tried with success but doesn't work:

```
Liferay.Util.openWindow({
    dialog: {centered: true}, 
    id:'myID', 
    title: 'Title', 
    uri: _url
}).on("success", function(){
    alert("Loading Complete");
});
```

Comment: And what are you showing in that popup? Of what is this `_url`?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could try listening to the `visibleChange` event in your `dialog: { centered: true, on: { visibleChange: function(event) { if (event.newVal) { alert('dialogOpened'); } } } }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a local view / jsp of portlet using that `_url`, I would recommand to call that `functionToBeExecuted` on `window.onload` or jQuery `document.ready` in that respective jsp.

However, if not, there is still a work-arround you can try with i.e. to add delay (`setTimeout`) to the `functionToBeExecuted` as following:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript: showDialog();">Show Dialog</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog(){
        AUI().ready(function(A) {
            Liferay.Util.openWindow({
                dialog: {centered: true}, 
                id: 'myID', 
                title: 'Title', 
                uri: _url 
            });

            setTimeout(functionToBeExecuted, 3000);
        });
    }

    function functionToBeExecuted(){
        alert('Called!');
    }
</script>
```

**NOTE:** `functionToBeExecuted` is the name of the function, you desire to call.